# read file and run files as per file sequence listed in file with powershell

Tags: powershell

Requirement is need to read the **file (filelist.txt)** and run the files which present in different folder in sequence as per listed in filelist.txt with powershell script.

I have file named filelist.txt.

**filelist.txt contain below value**

```
VT_value.ps1
SAB_NUM.ps1
RAME_CHANGE.ps1
GAMT_VALU.ps1
```

Comment: Where's your attempted code?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `filelist.txt` is in the current directory, and the scripts are in `C:\path\to\scripts`, you could use the call operator (`&`) like this:

```
Get-Content filelist.txt |ForEach-Object {
    & (Join-Path C:\path\to\scripts $_)
}
```